# Unable to connect to headless rpi; rpi won't stay connected to router

Tags: ssh, ethernet, hard-drive, connection, headless

I got a raspberrypi 3 setup with Jessie (`2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie.img`), and everything working great with it.  It was connected to the router via ethernet, and I could connect either on my local wireless using the local IP address, or remotely using a static-IP that I setup.  At some point after setting up an external hard-drive, I was no longer able to connect to the Pi via SSH.  Either the request would timeout, or the `ssh` command would just hang indefinitely.  Then the Pi wouldn't stay connected to the router at all, and I couldn't access it with a direct ethernet connection either.

After that happened, I started from scratch, wiped the SD and got everything working dandy again.  But now the same thing has happened.  Maybe it's a coincidence, but maybe not, I was again trying to reformat this USB connected external harddrive.  When I restart the pi, or unplug and re-plugin the router (via ethernet) the router will show that the Pi is briefly connected, but then it will disconnect.  Even while it's connected to the router, I'm unable to access it via SSH.  When the router says it is connected to the pi, I'm also unable to ping its IP address (`Request timeout for icmp_seq...`)

I don't have a monitor/keyboard/mouse, so SSH is my only method of access.  Is there anything I can do besides starting over again?  What could be causing this?

It's possible that both times, the issues have appeared after trying to format/partition the external drive with `parted` and/or `fdisk`... but I'm not positive what I was doing at the time.  Nothing noticeable seemed to have occurred at the time.

---

Other Notes:

- The external HD is connected via a powered USB hub, so it doesn't seem likely that it's a power issue.
- The red-light is continuously on, the green light is flashing every second (or so) and the ethernet cable light flashes intermittently also.
- Both times when the RPi has been setup, I've run the firmware updates (via `sudo rpi-update`)
- The `/boot/ssh` file has been created (and I was able to SSH previously)
- WPA information is setup in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (and it was connected to the router fine previously).
- I currently can't connect, so I can't provide detailed version numbers, but I installed the 2017-01-11 raspbian jessie image, and updated the firmware in mid january (while it was still working fine).

Comment: > "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable".  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Comment: @Milliways interesting, thanks; the tutorials I read suggested that was a good standard practice.  Is there a different way to do *stable* firmware (etc) updates?

Comment: `dist-upgrade` is the recommended method, although with recent releases `upgrade` seems to do this. The latest supported kernel is `4.4.38` which you would have. See [Updating and Upgrading Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md)